# Почему выводится отрицательное число?

Tags: javascript

```
let product = {
name: "headphones",
price: 100,
discount: 0
}
 const obj = object => {
 if (object.price > 100){
   return object.price / 100 * 10 - object.price
  } else {
    return object.price * 7 / 100 - object.price
  }
  }
  console.log(obj(product))
```

Comment: произведи отладку, да посмотри что где у тебя происходит...

Comment: наверняка какая-нибудь путанница в знаках и их приоритетности. (интересно, а что ты ожидал)

Comment: Так левые части тут обе меньше чем правые. Это как `0.1*x - x` и `0.07*x - x` при положительном `x` оба варианта будут отрицательные, конечно.

Comment: price Поделить на 100 и умножить на 10 и вычесть полученное число из price

Comment: Вот. "Вычесть полученное число из price" - это значит `price` слева, а справа то, что вы подсчитали. А у вас наоборот сделано.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Забавно получилось, что написано на бумажке одно, а в коде ровно наоборот %)))